# How to show the drop down box when something is typed in the text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a click listener for the select tag?
How do I trigger the select tag and show the dropdown box?
Like this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xqrW.png)

```
function myFunction(obj) {
  var dropdown= document.getElementById("dropdown");
  dropdown.click(); ???
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
  <select id="dropdown" onchange="this.previousElementSibling.value=this.value; this.previousElementSibling.focus()">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can do like below:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function(){
   $('#dropdown').attr('size',$('#dropdown option').length);
  }); 
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text"/><br><br>
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Note:-  You can use third-party plugin like below***

[editable-select](https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select)

***Working example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function(){
   $('#dropdown').editableSelect('show');;
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text"/><br><br>
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant the dropdown window for the option list. not the box itself

Comment: so you want to open drop-down when any character write in text-box?

Comment: Haha, I got the same code from [link](http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/) before you updated your answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select

This jquery plugin works for me

Answer (score 1):

you can't really do that with a selctbox. One workaround would be to set the selectbox size to a number greater than 0. You can expand this to get the exact height of the selectbox (= number of options) and set it as attribute size:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function(){
    $('#dropdown').focus().attr('size', 3);
  }); 
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text"/>
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```